How to create generic Map function for generic data structure List[T any]
I'm trying to implement a generic List[T] data structure that allow chaining method but get stuck.
My struct definition:
type List[T any] struct {
    elements []T
    count    int
}

My interface:
type IMapper[I any, O any] interface {
    Map(func(I) O) List[O]
}

The problem is my list only has 1 generic type T and I can't declare another type. First version (doesn't work):
// Method cannot have type parameters
func (receiver *List[T]) Map[R any](mapperFunc func(T) R) *List[R] {
    ans := New[R]()

    for _, element := range receiver.elements {
        ans.Add(mapperFunc(element))
    }

    return ans
}

Second version:
func (receiver *List[T]) Map(mapper func(T) any) *List[any] {
    var ans = New[any]()
    for _, element := range receiver.elements {
        ans.Add(mapper(element))
    }

    return ans
}

It works. However, the IDE typing suggestion would treat the result as List[any] and I have to do type conversion. Is there any way that I can achieve a result like map in TypeScript or Java?

you have to use a top-level function that takes your List[T] as argument
